# Algebra symbology guidance for Ethereum Yellow Paper

Tags: yellow-paper

There are numerate people who have limited experience in interpreting the algebra used in computer science papers. Therefore, it would be most useful if there were a list of all algebraic symbols used in [the Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper), along with their definition as applied in the paper.

There is of couse [this guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), however, for some of the symbols, there are multiple interpretaions.

**Please list the symbols used and define their meaning**.  My understanding is as in my answer below. I've used bold italics where I'm particularly unsure. Please point out where I am wrong.

**EDIT** - *I've posted the list as a community wiki.*

Comment: Good idea. You should take the list and post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: If you make the answer a community wiki, it will be easy for people to add their own definitions to your answer

Comment: Is this asking for guidance of the notation such as Gavin's use of lowercase sigma for state transitions, or was it intended as only the definitions of the more general use mathematical notation as given below?

Comment: @bekah a complete list of all the character's and their meaning would be useful and could be added here (or another question asked).  I was mainly looking for the mathemtical notation originally.

Comment: *characters (!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Univerally recognised mathematical symbols and their name/meaning**

[image: ≡]    is defined as/is equivalent to

[image: =]    is equal to

[image: ≠]    is not equal to

[image: ‖...‖]    size (length) of

[image: ∈]    is in the following set

[image: ∉]    is not in the following set

[image: ∀]    for all

[image: ∪]    union (common elements in adjacent sets)

[image: ∧]    ***and***

[image: :]    such that

[image: {}]   ***set***

[image: ()]   ***function or tuple***

[image: []]   array indexing

[image: ∨]   or (e.g. eq 11), ***Unsure for equations 24 and 29***

[image: _>]   greater than

[image: _+]   addition

[image: _-]   subtraction

[image: ∑]   summation

[image: {]   either or --- generally used to denote cases, for example piecewise functions with behaviour like 'if this, that. Otherwise, this different thing'.

[image: |...|]   ***no. bytes of (e.g. eq 96)***

[image: ⌊...⌋] floor; lowest element in

[image: ⌈...⌉] ceiling; highest element in

[image: ⊕]     exclusive or

[image: [ *a*, *b*)] real numbers greater than or equal to *a* and less than *b*

[image: ∅] empty set

[image: ·] sequence concatenation (e.g. equations 166,227)

[image: ∃] there exists

---

**Symbols which have a specific meaning in the Yellow Paper, but are not universally used in general mathematics**

𝔹<sub>n</sub> hash of size *n* bytes

Answer (score 0):

Handy reference to the symbols. Not sure this is 100% accurate, pull request appreciated.

https://github.com/deepakraous/ethereum-spec/tree/master/symbols